# What do I do if a tag needs correction?

Tags: discussion, tags

*This question was a response to a tag with a spelling mistake.*

I have enough rep to create tags, but I don't see an option to edit them yet.

I can think of several ways I could handle this:

1. Post it here as a question (so someone with enough rep can correct the tag)
2. flag a question with that tag for moderator attention with a note

Is there a preferred method for addressing errors discovered in the tags?

Comment: Looks like it has been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a few questions and you have sufficient reputation, correct it. Otherwise post it on meta.

Correcting can be creating a new tag spelled correctly or even reworded altogether for clarity.

Comment: At what reputation (and where) does it become correctable?

Comment: 200 rep allows you to retag

Comment: OK, so I should have created a new correctly spelled tag and retagged it to that.

Comment: That is what I did. folksonomy tagging is all about managing them as a group

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was thinking of the tool that someone used for the rename of the [dd] -> [dnd].

Comment: Synonyms require 1000 reputation and are voted on. Its easier just to retag for this sort of thing.

Comment: Yeah, you don't really even need to post it on meta - there's plenty of meddling people with rep that'll get to it tout suite :-)

Comment: I had missed the spelling error on that one so I'm glad it was pointed out.